# Swift: Table View - Signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

According to my other thread, I have a signal SIGABRT error in my code. The code consists of:

A Storyboard with 1 TableView and 1 Table Cell included
A custom Tablecell class (TableViewCell_Prototyp), which is connected to the Storyboard by (strong) IBoutlets.
A View Controller class, which is described in the following.

My ViewController class is connected to 3 super-classes: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource. In addition, there are 3 functions implemented. Can somebody find the mistake ?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

i don't know what happens here. It was written by default so it should not cause any errors.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

i just want one table cell to be returned.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell (withIdentifier: "picCell") as! TableViewCell_Prototyp
    cell.shoutPic.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bildschirmfoto 2017-06-05 um 10.11.21")
    cell.shoutText.text = "Hallooooooooo"
      return cell
}
```

shoutPic and shoutText is connected to the TableViewCell_Prototype custom class by outlets.

Comment: What's the complete error message? Which line of code exactly is causing the error?

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 1):

When you have custom table cell classes registered for your tableView, it's better to dequeue them using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)`, like so:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "picCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell_Prototyp
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is all of your code, I would check that your prototype cell's identifier matches "picCell" exactly and that its class is set to `TableViewCell_Prototyp`

I think @Gereon is right that you need to dequeue with a different method.

Having the class `TableViewCell_Prototyp` is not enough -- you need to set it to the cell in the Storyboard file.  Click on the cell in the storyboard and set it in the Identity tab.

Comment: It is. I reduced the complexity to a minimum and it is still not working. You find the TableViewCell_Protoyp class in the following.

Comment: import UIKit

class TableViewCell_Prototyp: UITableViewCell {    

    @ IBOutlet var shoutPic: UIImageView!
    @ IBOutlet var shoutText: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}